# Finding the example of an operator such that $|| T^2||\ne || T||^2 $

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have to find an example of an operator that satisfied $|| T^2||\ne || T||^2 $

I use the proof of the norm of an operator, to find this, however I am not convinced that this is enough.

Since

$$||T^2||\leq||T||\cdot ||T||$$, we then need to find an operator such that $$||T^2||<||T||^2$$.

If:

$$||T||=||T||\longrightarrow ||T^2||=||(T)||\cdot||(T)||$$

So by the inequality said above, I should prove that:

$$\frac{||(Tx)||\cdot||(Tx)||}{||x||\cdot ||{x}||}<\bigg(\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}\bigg)^2$$

Then it can be used that:

$${\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)||\cdot||(Tx)||={\sup}_{||x||=1}||\frac{1}{||x||}Tx\cdot\frac{1}{||x||}Tx||$$

with $||z||=\frac{x}{||x||}$ we get

$$||(Tx)^2)||={\sup}_{||z||=1}||Tz||\cdot{\sup}_{||z||=1}||Tz||$$

Since $$||T^2||=||T||^2$$

$${\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)^2||={\sup}_{||z||=1}||Tz||\cdot {\sup}_{||z||=1}||Tz||={\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)||^2$$

and by $$||{A^2}||<||{A}^2||$$

$${\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)^2||={\sup}_{||z||=1}||Tz||\cdot {\sup}_{||z||=1}||Tz||<{\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)||^2$$

So we obtain:

$${\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)^2||=c||z||\cdot c||z||<{\sup}_{||x||=1}||(Tx)||^2$$

iff  $$||{z}||<1$$ and $x$ is a real-valued function.

Any ideas how I can find a simple answer to this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know an example of matrix $M$ such that $M^{2}=0$ but $M \neq 0$?

Comment: I am not really, sure, all I was given is the hint that $$||AB||\leq||A||\cdot ||B||$$

Comment: Why start with $||T^2||=||T||\cdot ||T||$ when you want to show this is not true in general?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I corrected it

Comment: @geetha290krm the nilpontent matrix, $N^k$

Comment: $A =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \,\, 0\\ 1\,\, 0\end{bmatrix}  $

Comment: Yes, I see that now. thanks for the hint

Comment: "Since the norm is $||T||=||Tx||\longrightarrow ||T^2||=||(Tx)^2||$": no! $||T||\ne||Tx||$ and $||(Tx)^2||$ means nothing. All computations after this sentence are likewise nonsense.

Comment: @AnneBauval nice to see you. Please check the corrected version.

Comment: Corrected. thanks

Comment: No, you did not correct $||T||=||Tx||.$ And $||T^2||$ is even less equal to $||Tx||^2.$ And (happily!) what you should prove is not $\frac{||(Tx)||\cdot||(Tx)||}{||x||\cdot ||{x}||}<\bigg(\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}\bigg)^2.$ Etc.